# Getting a weird exception Unparseable date: "6 Aug 2012"

Tags: java, android

I got a date time format - `"dd MMM yyyy"`, when trying to parse "6 Aug 2012", I get an java.text.ParseException Unparseable date.

Every thing looks fine, do you see the problem?

Comment: Can you show your code? One possible cause is that you are not using a compatible locale (to recognize Aug as a month, you need Locale.ENGLISH for example).

Comment: Is "Aug" a known thing in your _current_ locale?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to mention the Locale as well...

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("6 Aug 2012");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = sdf.parse("6 Aug 2012");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. You will need to provide a locale

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("6 Aug 2012");
```

Or

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", new Locale("EN")).parse("6 Aug 2012");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split()` function with the **delimiter** `" "`

```
String s = “6 Aug 2012”;

String[] arr = s.split(" ");

int day = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
String month = arr[1];
int year = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
```

Comment: Are you recommending to parse a date with String#split?

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are correct but outdated and since this question is still being visited, here is the modern answer.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. This will work with your Android version/minSDK:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String str = "6 Aug 2012";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

> 2012-08-06

In the format pattern java.time uses just one `d` for either one or two digit day of month. For year you may use either of `yyyy`, `uuuu`, `y` and `u`. And as the others have said, specify locale. If `Aug` is English, then an English-speaking locale.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- Similar question to this one: [Java - Unparseable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154772/java-unparseable-date).
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Question: `uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java)
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.