# java Unparseable date:

Tags: java, date

how to parse this date ?

```
Mon Jul 29 02:00:00 CEST 2013
```

the code:

```
    public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        try {
                String startdateString = "Mon Jul 29 02:00:00 CEST 2013";
        SimpleDateFormat fromUser2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss z yyyy");

            startdateString = myFormat.format(fromUser2.parse(startdateString));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

i am getting following exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Jul 29 02:00:00 CEST 2013"

16:13:57,761 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: How are you creating this `myFormat` variable? I changed it to `fromUser2` and runs without problems.

Comment: This question was [already answered][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154816/34880

Comment: @Fernando: Ah - agreed, "Mon" won't be a valid day in the default locale.  Voting as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide any `Locale` and the code won't work if you don't run it on an english locale (as US or UK).

The following code (corrected) work for me:

```
try {
    String startdateString = "Mon Jul 29 02:00:00 CEST 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat fromUser2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    System.out.println(fromUser2.parse(startdateString));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Instead posting two similar answers, provide just one and edit it.

Comment: By the way, I've tested it using `d` instead of your proposal `dd` and works fine...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm not sure if this is a problem with SO or with my browser, but I never wanted to post twice.

Comment: @LaurentG No need to write Locale and dd. There is just problem of using object of SimpleDateFormat to format the date.

Answer (score 2):

You need to format your date using SimpleDateFormat's object.

Replace

```
startdateString = myFormat.format(fromUser2.parse(startdateString));
```

By

```
startdateString = fromUser2.format(fromUser2.parse(startdateString));
```

Answer (score 1):

i could not find this answer on google but ok is alread here :

[Java - Unparseable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154772/java-unparseable-date/6154816#6154816)

```
try {
String startdateString = "Mon Jul 29 02:00:00 CEST 2013";
SimpleDateFormat fromUser2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

  System.out.println(fromUser2.parse(startdateString));
 } catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```