# Android SimpleDateFormat returning dots in am and pm

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format

I am using the following code to get the current time as a String in Android.

```
public String getTime(){

   Date date = new Date();
   String strTimeFormat = "hh:mm a";
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strTimeFormat);
   String formattedTime= dateFormat.format(date);
   return formattedTime;
}
```

The response on few mobiles I get properly as expected but on few mobiles, I am getting dots in a.m. or p.m.

for example 
08:02 p .m .

this is how I am getting the data while I am supposed to get it like 
08:02 pm

my question is how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe this has to do with the Locale. Replace dots with empty string, like: `String formattedTime= dateFormat.format(date).replace(".", "");`

Comment: i can try this , its a workaround but looking for a perfect solution.

Comment: As an aside consider not using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They are old and troublesome. Instead you may add ThreeTenABP to your project and use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: BTW it's a locale preblem. Just specifyvthe locale that your user wants.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Unparseable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154772/java-unparseable-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code. Hope it works !

```
private String getTimeStamp() {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aaa", Locale.ENGLISH);
            return df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        }
```

Comment: i will try and let know.