# Java Android Studio - Unparseable date error on phisycal device with Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, date, simpledateformat, android-10.0

This part of code make a sort of conversion from an input like "January 1, 2020" to "01/01". The whole code works perfectly on devices with Android up to Pie and in AVD with devices with Q and R too. When I try to run it on phisycal Android devices with Android Q it doesn't run (I tried with 2 different devices a Mi Note 10 and a OnePlus 6T). I did a check on the debugger and I found this error as soon as it go in the IF loop (I think in the instruction: @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");"

W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Nov 05 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020"

```
       String[] mese = new String[] {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
       int a= 0 ;

       while (a < 12){ 
                    if(dato.contains(mese[a])){ 
                             System.out.println("Test 3");
                             DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                             Date date = format.parse(dato);
                             @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
                             Date date2 = dt.parse(String.valueOf(date));
                             @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
                             assert date2 != null;
                             dato = dato.replaceAll(dato,dt1.format(date2));
                    }
                    a++;
                }
```

my pattern is wrong? I tried EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy and EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy but same results

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I'll try to do that. BTW, still no idea about my issue :/

Comment: As feedback. I totally converted the code using the new Java.time and this solved my compatibility issue with Android Q (and R) on phisycal devices. It seems they don't like SimpleDataFormat

Comment: Great to hear! I’d love if you would post that as an answer to your own question for other readers to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and desugaring or ThreeTenABP

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

java.time formatters are thread-safe, so we often prefer to declare them static:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter sourceFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
private static final DateTimeFormatter targetFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM");
```

Now your conversion goes like this:

```
    String dato = "November 5, 2020";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dato, sourceFormatter);
    dato = date.format(targetFormatter);
    System.out.println(dato);
```

Output:

> 05/11

### What went wrong in your code?

It seems to me that you were doing your format conversion in a way that was more complicated than needed. Rather than checking if there’s a month name in the string, why not just try to parse it? If there wasn’t, my code would throw a `DateTimeParseException` which you may then catch and handle the way that is appropriate to your situation. Your code was converting your `String` to `Date` to `String` to `Date` again and to `String` again. I didn’t understand the reason. Also you were using the `SimpleDateFOrmat` class. It is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. The second time you parsed from `String` to `Date` failed, and I bet I know why: For your first `SimpleDateFormat` you had remembered to specify `Locale.ENGLISH`, but you forgot on your second `SimpleDateFormat`. The string contained `Thu` and `Nov` in English, so if your Android Q and R devices had a different language setting, this explains. Finally for your purpose this line:

```
    dato = dato.replaceAll(dato,dt1.format(date2));
```

is the same as the simpler:

```
    dato = dt1.format(date2);
```

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. The latter is called ThreeTenABP. When using ThreeTenABP make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- Similar question: [Java - Unparseable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154772/java-unparseable-date)

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way not using anymore SimpleDateFormat:

```
         while (a < 12){
                    if(dato.contains(mese[a])){

                        String dateInString = dato;
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                        LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(dateInString, formatter);
                        DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM");
                        String newDate = dateTime.format(f2);
                        dato = dato.replaceAll(dato,newDate);

                    }
                    a++;
                }
```